# Juniper rpm configuration - http probe bad request

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

I am trying to configure a RPM probe to ping a web service using an IP address, using junos version 12.1x

```
probe My-Probe {
    test My-Test 
        probe-type http-get
        target url http://10.10.10.11:8080/services/id/1 
        probe-interval 30
        test-interval 60 
}
```

The web service is up and running, I can hit the target url successfully with any other client.  For example, in the shell on the same router i can use

```
fetch http://10.10.10.11:8080/services/id/1
```

And see the 200/OK response.

The issue is, when the RPM probe tries to hit the target url, it doesn't work.  The server responds with a 400/Bad Request error, "Invalid Hostname".  Investigating with wireshark, I can see a malformed get request:

```
GET /services/id/1 HTTP/1.1\r\n
\r\n
```

That's it - it's missing a "Host" header, just as the web service host machine indicated.

What do I have to do to send a correctly formatted get request? 
What i would expect to see:

```
GET /services/id/1 HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: 10.10.10.11:8080\r\n
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, JunOS does not support those feature at this time.

port number and sub url does not work.

In the RPM target url only supported FQHN such as
`target url http://10.10.10.11/` 
`target url http://SERVERA/`

You should feature request to juniper.